# Labview converting hexformatted string to ascii

Tags: labview

In labview I am trying to convert a hex string to ascii format. For example if I have a hexstring like: 09124E4F21CD0024FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF the ascii version of this is : NO!Í or basically a bunch of illegible symbols. I tried using the labview functions of converting hexstring to number but they didn't work. How would I convert the ascii part to hexformatted ascii?

Comment: Terminology around 'hex' is always confusing so just to be clear: you have a LabVIEW string containing the character `0`, the character `9`, the character `1`, the character `2` and so on, and you want the output to be another LabVIEW string containing the character with ASCII code `x09`, the character with ASCII code `x12`, and so on. Is that correct?

Comment: ....or is "09" the first ASCII Char, "12" the second one and so on...

Comment: Ok so the hexstring is in hexformat, and the ascii code  currently is the weird symbols, so yes I want to try to get the output being ascii code 09, 12, and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Hexadecimal String to Number](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361P-01/glang/hex_string_to_number/) works fine, but only for a hex string that represents a number that can be stored as a numeric data type:

> If the input string represents a number outside the range of the
>   representation of `number`, `number` is set to the maximum value for that
>   data type.

Your example input is 128 bits long whereas the longest integer data type in current LabVIEW is 64 bits.

You can use this function, but you need to convert the input one byte at a time:

- Create a While Loop and add a shift register. Initialise the shift register with your input string.
- Inside the loop, wire the string from the shift register to the `string` input of a [Search/Split String](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361P-01/glang/search_split_string/) function
- Wire a numeric constant of 2 to the `offset` input - i.e. split the string into the first two characters, and the rest
- Wire the `match + rest of string` output to the right-hand shift register terminal
- Wire the `substring before match` output to a Hexadecimal String to Number function
- Wire the `default` input of this function to a numeric constant with value 0 and type `U8`
- Wire the output of this function to the right-hand side of the While loop and make the terminal indexing (via right-click)
- Use an [Empty String/Path?](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361P-01/glang/empty_string_path/) function to exit the While loop when the string being passed back into the shift register is empty.

The output from the indexing terminal you created will now be a U8 (byte) array containing the data converted from the input string. If you want it in string form you can convert it using [Byte Array to String](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361P-01/glang/byte_array_to_string/).

This assumes that your input string is always a multiple of 2 characters in length. If you need it to handle an input such as `"3F2"` you'll need to check for this and do something to the input (I'll let you figure out what) before passing it into your loop.